# Command help on UNIX

Tags: unix

I need to know if we have any command on UNIX such that:
It gives me all the files which got updated after time t in the current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find` command for this.

Touch a file with your specific date and then use that file with the `-newer` parameter of `find`.

```
# To find all files modifed on 10th of Dec:

touch -t 12100000 foo
#        MMDDhhmm

find ./ -type f -maxdepth 1 -newer foo
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` with the `mtime` parameter:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1h30m
```

Comment: That's funny. I'm sure I didn't answer this question! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` command with appropriate arguments. Relevant information is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Age-Ranges).

Answer (score 1):

```
#find files by modification time
-------------------------------
find . -mtime 1               # 24 hours
find . -mtime -7              # last 7 days
find . -mtime -7 -type f      # just files
find . -mtime -7 -type d      # just dirs


find with time: this works on mac os x
--------------------------------------
find / -newerct '1 minute ago' -print
```